# What is the difference between $\overset{\Delta}{=}$ and := (delta-equal and :=)?

Tags: notation

Both symbols $\overset{\Delta}{=}$ and := are used for definition but I want to know the exact difference of them?

Comment: I use $\doteq$ for definitions, too.

Comment: Well, one has a $\Delta$ on top of the $=,$ and the other has a $:$ to the left of the $=.$ :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.  Some people use one notation, and some people use the other.  (And most people use neither, and just write a plain $=$ for definitions.)